Generic Spring Rigid Body Constraint Objects Jittering
I am working on a rigid body bike that binds four cylinders as wheels with generic spring rigid body constraints. It looks like this in Blender 4.1:

I believe that the constraints are set properly, for example locking all other rotation axis except for their y axis and only allowing them to be a little bouncy on the z axis.
Major settings are like:

X Angle:

X Lower 0 deg
Upper 0 deg


Z Angle:

Z Lower 0 deg
Upper 0 deg


Linear:

Z Axis stiffness 500, damping 10


Then I put a passive rigid plane under the bike and slightly rotate it to make it a slope.
But when I press space key to play, the bike go smoothly for just a few frames and those wheels suddenly start jittering and throw the whole vehicle into the sky.

And I've googled and tried a bunch of methods that does not work:

Applying all scales
Changing all collision shapes from convex hull into mesh
Checking disable collisions in constraint settings
Making the model bigger
Simplifying geometries

And I've found some unstable ways to stop the bike from being crazy:

Reducing surface friction to 0
Turning mass to an extremely big value
Easing the angle of the slope

But I don't think these are the right ways because if you change some other values in the scene then madness happened again. And obviously there is no reason to tweak these values if I don't want them to be like this.
Could anyone tell me what is going wrong and how to fix it? Thanks a lot!
BTW I've start a new file to recreate the scene in a much low-poly way but same thing happens again, so I am wondering whether some global settings went wrong, or that it was just me making some stupid mistakes.
.Blend file as follow:


Please share your Blend file so that someone can have a look at it.  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

@JohnEason thanks for your reminder! <3

Well I think I have figured it out, but in a really strange way.
I just rotated my whole model for 90 degrees, recreated four wheels and constraints, and finally switched the constraints' rotation axis to X axis. And no more jittering.
So now I consider it as a bug. (Maybe? I would rather it not be. Bugs are annoying.)
If someone knows what is wrong exactly, please tell me! Thanks!
